# Use a WCF - ProtoBuf client by generating code with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, protobuf-net

I'm used to consume WCF clients in my ASP.NET Core applications by generating the code with Visual Studio from the `wsdl` file (right-click or "Connected Services" & "Add Connected Service").

But now, I have to consume a service that returns an unique `proto` tag as a response. I've found that's because the used serializer is ProtoBuf.

Is it possible to use this service like I'm used to? I mean with a generated code. I'd rather not spend time writing the DTOs and the contracts (I've several big services to consume). I've seen no option so far to change the deserializer in the generated code, neither I've found a way to change the deserializer used by the client when I'm constructing it. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Bit of an outside chance, but have you seen [this page](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated)? - _"This page describes exactly what C# code the protocol buffer compiler generates for any given protocol definition. Note that you can only generate C# code from files using the newer proto3 syntax._

Comment: @stuartd I've searched using various keywords, but I didn't see this page. Thank you.

Comment: are you using the Google tooling? or protobuf-net? it may change things... and I'm a little unclear: what do you have *now*, and what do you want to *create*? do you have a .proto? or a plain (vanilla) WCF service? or a WCF service that is using protobuf-net? or...?

Comment: @MarcGravell Sorry for being unclear. I don't know anything else than aspnet core, so WCF is still mysterious to me. AFAIK, the service is a standard WCF service that uses `protobuf-net` as serializer.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios well, it can't be a "standard WCF service" if it is using protobuf-net :) but: what piece isn't working currently? I'm very unclear what is/isn't working (side note: I'm the author of protobuf-net)

Comment: @MarcGravell I was unaware that the service used protobuf, so I was using it like every other service. After writing my integration tests, I've seen that every call returned `null`, that's when I understood. The service seems to be declared as any service, with a `IFooService` marked with `[ServiceContract]` etc. My goal is to consume this service with as little work as possible, just like I do usually :P

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios well, if "mex" is working (for some value of working), you can *probably* do this pretty easily; main problem with "mex" is that it doesn't properly retain the field order - it tends to offset them by one; have a check to see whether this is the case, i.e. the problem is that it has changed `[DataMember(Order=1)]` to `[DataMember(Order=0)]`. If it has: protobuf-net has a hack for that: in a partial class you can use `[ProtoContract(DataMemberOffset = 1)] partial class YourType{}`